# No EndOfStream check on TextReader

Tags: c#, streamreader, textreader

I found that this problem is not addressed in this knowledge base and decided to add the question and the answer to help others.

I am creating a `TextReader` to read through a text file line by line using `ReadLine`, which requires a termination check for the end of this stream.

```
TextReader TR = new TextReader("MyFile.txt");
while (!TR.EndOfStream) // fails to compile here
{
    // do something
}
```

The EndOfStream does not exist for the TextReader class and this code will not compile.

Answer (score -1):

The solution is relatively simple but may be missed by those new to C# and the .NET libraries (as well as experts who write code too quickly!).

The `TextReader` class is subclassed from `StreamReader`, and it is this latter class which provides the common functionality for all of its child classes.

Thus the solution is to declare the reader as a `StreamReader`, and then to instantiate it as a `TextReader`.

```
StreamReader TR = new TextReader("MyFile.txt");
while (!TR.EndOfStream) // it finds this property now
{
// do something
}
```

Comment: Until you want to use a `StringReader` instead.

Comment: TextReader is abstract.. and it is StreamReader the one who is subclassed